# Margin as percentage in WPF's XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to make a UniformGrid take 70% of total window width and 80% of total window height. How achieve it?

```
<UniformGrid x:Name="Grid" Margin="20,0,0,0">

</UniformGrid>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF/XAML Databinding Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596943/wpf-xaml-databinding-question)

Comment: @Eugene I have wrote this question because I do not understand solutions from other topic. I do not know how to use solutions from this other topic.

Answer (score 7):

Like the other answer suggests, you first create a Grid like so:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
     <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
     <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <UniformGrid x:Name="yourGrid">
  </UniformGrid>
</Grid>
```

Then you set your UniformGrid control as the child in the 0th row 0th column of the main grid. The x* notation means that you want x parts of the screen used in the row/column, so splitting rows at 8*/2* splits them at 80%/20% and splitting columns and 7*/3* splits them at 70%/30%. I hope that clears it up for you.

Comment: XAML is invalid but I corrected it, the problem is that still I do not know how to make a UniformGrid a part of (0,0) (column,row).

Comment: Like so: <Uniform Grid x:Name="yourName" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"><UniformGrid>. However, you don't need to specify row and col parameters if they are equal to 0, like in the answer above.